# Sharing /home/ directory between a Native OS and a Virtual Machine kept on the same HD

Tags: linux, rsync, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bootable

Windows is my daily driver, but I have been learning programming lately and want to do my learning within a Linux environment. I want to be able to use Linux on both my home PC and laptop (but with the files in sync), so I assume my best option is to keep everything on an external SSD I can take with me.

My home desktop PC runs Windows and is quite powerful, so performance is not an issue. For it, a virtual machine is preferable so that I can use Linux while still having access to games and Windows-specific apps in the background.

My laptop is not very powerful, so virtual machines are not ideal. The only time I use it is for learning-related activities, however, so I do not care about its native OS. I'd be happy to run Linux natively on it.

My idea is to create two partitions on the SSD: one partition will house a native, bootable Linux install, and the other will house a virtual machine file. When on my laptop, I will boot from the "native" partition. When at home, I will run Linux from the VM partition.

To keep files in sync, I was thinking I could change the VM's /home/ to point to the native OS's /home/ on the other partition. Would this work? As I am inexperienced with Linux, I am not sure if this would cause problems. The distros would both be the same, of course (probably Xubuntu).

Also, is there a way for me to keep them synced down to even installed apps and packages and stuff? Or, is there a better solution for my problem?

Comment: That's possible. But did you know you can run the native installation in a VM?

Comment: I investigated that briefly and was left with the impression that involved "cloning" the native install into a VM file, thus de syncing the two as they are no longer one. Your comment made me revisit that assumption, however, and it sounds worth trying. If it works, this would probably be best. Thanks.

Comment: If you can attach the home partition to the VM, you may as well attach the install partition to the VM too, instead of having two copies of it, and if it's attached to the VM, the VM should be able to boot it. I've done this exact thing in VirtualBox although it was a while ago so I don't remember the exact steps. A VM image is basically just a fake hard drive after all - a real one works too.

Comment: If both the laptop AND the VM have compatible CPUs (e.g. both i386 or both amd64  - and note that you can run a 386 VM on an amd64 host), you don't need to have two partitions.  You can have an SSD with a native Linux installation on it that you can boot directly on the laptop **AND** boot the same installation in a VM on your desktop.  Just tell the VM to use the appropriate device node (e.g. /dev/sdX1) to boot from.  You do, of course, have to be careful to properly shutdown the laptop and the VM when you want to switch where it's being used, but you'd have to do that anyway.